# Variegated rubber plant blotches on leaf edges

Tags: leaves

I have a pot with 3 plants in them. The planter is self watering. I thought it was the weak British summer sun. But it cant be because the leaves not taking the brunt of light are getting it as well and its been a gloomy two weeks and leaves are still developing it.

I saw some webbing when this plant arrived. I suspected mealy bugs but I don’t see any evidence of it currently.

Another thing I have noticed is that the sheath covering the new growths is a very light shade of chalky white pink compared to a few months ago and the exposed nodes are much smaller after each leaf unfurls.

What could it be ?

[image]

[image]